# Grouping filter button not working in wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I tried using "//" label separator to group filters buttons. But it is not grouping the  buttons. If I named the buttons `DNS // Response` and `DNS // Request` then two buttons are created with name  `DNS // Response` and `DNS // Request` and are not grouped under the name `DNS` which  doesn't follow the specification in wireshark documentation.

> For example if you create buttons named “Not Squirrels // Rabbits” and “Not Squirrels // Capybaras” they will show up in the toolbar under a single button named “Not Squirrels”.

I couldn't find another way of grouping these buttons. So my question is what is wrong here and how can I group these buttons?

System: Ubuntu 20.04 
Wireshark version: 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have indicated that your Wireshark version is 3.2.3, but the filter button grouping feature wasn't introduced until version 3.4.0.  See: https://www.wireshark.org/news/20201029.html

If you want to be able to create filter button groups, you'll have to upgrade your version of Wireshark to at least version 3.4.0.